# Quickfilter should add value to list of filters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-admin, query-string

I have a list of custom filters for a basic list in react-admin like this:

```js
const ClientListsFilter = (props: FilterProps): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <Filter {...props}>
      <TextInput label="First Name" source="firstName" resettable />
      <TextInput label="Last Name" source="lastName" resettable />
      <TextInput label="E-Mail" source="email" resettable />
      <QuickFilter label="Has Event Accepted" source="hasEventAccepted" defaultValue={true} />
    </Filter>
  )
}
```

When I selected now the `QuickFilter` "Has Event Accepted" it adds the following to the query: `hasEventAccepted%22%3Atrue` which is to be expected.

Now, I want to add multiple such "Has Event XYZ" `QuickFilters`, but instead of having a pair for each in the query it would make sense to just have a list like `hasEvents=[1,2,3]`

Is there a way to achieve this in react-admin? How could I combine multiple values so that a `QuickFilter` will add directly multiple such events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `<Filter>` component, you can't - it doesn't support your use case.

So you have 2 options:

1. [Write a custom Filter component](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/FilteringTutorial.html#building-a-custom-filter) that does what you want
2. Name each quick filter in a different way (e.g. `hasEventAccepted`, `hasEventDeclined`, etc.), and convert them to a single `hasEvent` query parameter in your `dataProvider.getList()` code.

Comment: Thanks. I actually use now a SelectArrayInput and it covers almost everything I need (except for the pre-saved quick combination of multiple filters as a shortcut).